# Choosing functions so $p'(r) = g(r) \cdot (1- \frac{p(r)}{k(r)})$ is solvable

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to modify the verhulst equation to give it certain desirable qualities, however I keep hitting dead ends. Here is the general form of the equation I am starting with:

$$ p'(r) = g(r) \cdot (1- \frac{p(r)}{k(r)}) $$

Obviously both functions $g(r)$ and $k(r)$ will be defined before solving the equation. My question is essentially how I can find an equation for each of those functions such that the following properties are true.

## Scope

- I only care about the behavior of the relevant functions between 0 and 1 for $r$.
- All values/variables will be Real values, no Complex or anything like that.

## Desired Properties

1. All integrals should be solvable symbolically, no taylor series or any sort of numerical approximations.
2. Likewise $p(r)$ should be symbolically differentiable and integratable. As well as be computationally feasible and contain only common math functions like Log, e^x, factorial, modulus, +, -, but nothing more obscure or hard to program like Gamma or Hypergeometric functions. Basically something I can translate to source code easily.
3. The resulting function $p(r)$ is $p(0) = 0$ and monotonically increases approaching infinity as r approaches 1.
4. $g(r)$ is monotonically increasing as well with $g(0) = 0$ and with it approaching infinity as r approaches 1.
5. Likewise $k(r)$ is monotonically increasing approaching infinity as $r$ approaches 1 however in this case $k(0) > 0$. More specifically the value of k when r is 0 should be defined as a constant defined in the function k. For example $k(0) = K$
6. Both $k(r)$ and $g(r) should have constants defined such that they act as shaping variables to adjust

## Attempts

While I have not been able to solve the problem with all the desirable properties above I have gotten close. but I am always missing one or more of the above properties. Thankfully I can show some graphs of examples of the above functions to give you an idea of what I'm looking to do.

### Attempting $g(x)$

I have mostly been using the following equation for $g(x)$.

$$ g(r)=A*\frac{r}{(1-r)^B} $$

In this case $A$ and $B$ are my shaping variables. Here is a plot of the function showing different shaping variables. I will plot it below.

[image: g(r)]

In the above I am showing the function with shaping variables A=1,B=1 and A=4,B=4 and A=1,B=4.

If I use this equation for g I can solve the problem just fine and get a result that meets my desired property when k(r) is a constant. But not when $k(r)$ is a more complex function with my desired properties.

Incase it is helpful I will show the solution I get for $p(r)$ to the above equation when k is a constant K.

$$ g(r) = K-K e^{-\frac{A(1-r)^{-B}\left((1-r)^B-B(r-1)r+r^2-1\right)}{(B-2)(B-1)K}} $$

**Note**: This solution seems to have the odd property that B cant be 1 or 2 exactly. Which is kinda unexpected.

Which would produce the following plot for A=5, B=3, K= 10.

[image: g(r) plotted]

### Attempting $k(r)$

For $k(r)$ I have tried several different functions. None of them produce something I can integrate by hand and neither can mathematica. There are some combinations with a different function for g (for example if I drop the B exponent) where I can integrate, but they have different problems.

One simple attempt I made, which as I said fails, but gives an idea as to what I am going for is where $k(r)$ is defined the same as $g(r)$ but simply adding some constant $K$.

$$ k(r) = g(r) + K $$

That would produce the following plot when the following shaping constants are used A = 0.1, B = 2, and K = 10

[image: plot of k(r)]

### Combining It All

Now I couldn't figure out how to combine the above equations exactly, as I said the integrals don't seem solvable. But I have gotten some similar equations with different shaping variables to integrate and work. For example if I dropped the $B$ shaping variable then solve the differential equation I can get a solution that sort of works.

Here is one set of functions that almost works:

$$ g(r) = \frac{A \cdot r}{1-r} $$

$$ k(r) = B(-r-\log(1-r)) + K $$

Giving the final solution of...

$$ p(r) = \frac{A\left((-K)^{\frac{A}{B}+1}(Br+B\log(1-r)-K)^{-\frac{A}{B}}-Br-B\log(1-r)+K\right)}{A+B} $$

Plotting that I get a graph that looks almost exactly like what I wanted.

[image: Final graph of g(r)]

In this case the blue line is $g(r)$, the red dashed horizontal line is $k(r)$ and the red dashed vertical line is the vertical asymptote at $r=1$.

There are a few problems with this, however, that, despite being close, isnt working. Specifically my solution has two problems, the first one being more dire than the second (if it were just the second I could live with it though it isn't ideal).

1. The property I mentioned above, #2 isnt satisfied. As far as I can tell $p(r)$ can not be symbolically integrated.
2. Since both $g(r)$ and $k(r)$ only have a single shaping variable each it isnt ideal for the application I am trying to use it for (this is why in the above failed attempts I added a second shaping variable).

The graph is exactly what I am looking for, a sigmoid that tappers off to infinity on the tail end.

## Conclusion

So what I am asking is either someone maybe help me find a way to combine and fix my above attempts to work as expected, or, suggest entirely new functions I can use that will be easier to work with and is solvable with the desired properties.

Comment: What do you mean by $g(r)$ can be solved symbolically? Do you mean its inverse function has a closed form?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I am not very good with math vocab... What I mean is once g(r) is solved for, I can then integrate g(r) and the result will be a typical equation rather than needing to rely on numerical representations.

Comment: In the equation $p'=g(1-p/k)$, what is given? Are you trying to solve for $p$ or $g$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire p and p' are being solved for. g and k will be given in the sense that I need to define what those are. The question is about picking appropriate functions for g and k that makes the problem solvable while also having the other properties I listed.

Comment: But then why do you need to integrate $g$ (as in your previous comment)?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Oops sorry, I misspoke. g itself never needs to be integrated, only as part of p. Let me edit the question to take that part out.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Question updated

Comment: What is the thing after "Giving the final solution of..."? Its not $g$, which you stated was chosen to be $Ar/(1-r)$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry you are correct of course, it should have been $p(r)$. I have corrected the question. Good catch!

Comment: well in which case aren’t you done then? :) or did you really want to solve the ODE, and then additionally find its integral in closed form?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I needed a solution for P that is both elementary (this solution satisfies that) and its integral is also elementary (this solution does not solve that property, as far as I can tell, I cant symbolically integrate it and neither can mathematica).

Comment: Yeah ok that’s what I feared. If this is for an application irl I would try hard to avoid needing the closed form answer :) gl

Comment: @CalvinKhor This is for a real life problem. But its also a concept I want to learn to do more generally as I've faced this issue many times before on other problems. What do you mean by "avoid needing the closed form answer"?

Comment: I mean, I would try to see if there are good approximations that are good enough for applications. Eg there are no real circles in engineering... for instance you could try polynomial quadrature to estimate the integral of p. and your dotted red line in your graph looks like a very good approximation for r close to 1. Coincidence? perhaps a matched asymptotic expansion would explain it. Useful? Depends on the use...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, so: ‘Closed form’ (a google-able phrase, like ‘first order linear ODE solution’ :)) is roughly the same as ‘elementary’.

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks, excellent input to consider.